# Snowflake, How to unload the data in a specific order to the stage (internal/external) in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-order-by

I am able to create internal stage in snowflake and unload the table data to the stage using "COPY INTO" command. The number of records in the table are huge (150K). So when I unload to the stage, there are 3 files created in random order. I want to save the data in ascending or descending order in the stage like we use in order by SQL clause. How can I achieve that?

```
Example:
stage_0_0_0.csv -> 1 to 50000
stage_0_1_0.csv -> 50001 to 100000
stage_0_2_0.csv -> 100001 to 150001
```

No need to be exactly the same above but should be in order. Also how can I combine all the three files into one file.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you all.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for 'PARTITION BY'. Refer (can be used for csv too) - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#partitioning-unloaded-rows-to-parquet-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you unload the data into a Stage if you just use `COPY INTO @stage from Table;` we do not guarantee the order of data.

However, if you use  Order by in the inner select as below, this will order the data as per the column name specified

```
COPY INTO @stage FROM (select * from source_table order by column_name) FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSVCOMPRESSION = GZIP FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"') INCLUDE_QUERY_ID = TRUE
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! How can I combine all the three csv files into one file?

Comment: @pmk add MAX_FILE_SIZE and SINGLE param while unloading. Maximum file size supported is 5 GB for Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, or Microsoft Azure stages.